# Mulesoft - DevKit Tutorial build failure (cookbook)

Tags: eclipse, maven, mule, anypoint-studio

I am working on the Tutorial and am running into the following error when I attempt to do a maven build  :

```
cd ~/dev/mule-cookbook
mvn install eclipse:eclipse
```

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sdk-client: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   com.cookbook.tutorial:sdk-client:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find
>   com.cookbook.tutorial:soap-server:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in
>   http://repository.jboss.com/ was cached in the local repository,
>   resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss
>   has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal on project sdk-client: Could not resolve dependencies for
>   project com.cookbook.tutorial:sdk-client:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure
>   to find com.cookbook.tutorial:soap-server:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in
>   http://repository.jboss.com/ was cached in the local repository,
>   resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss
>   has elapsed or updates are forced at ...

Any idea what I can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Over all the issue ended up being an incorrect version of JAVA.
DevKit requires 1.7 I guess.

Comment: Good on yoi for answering your own question, but the error output you gave above does not seem to support this.  Can you update your question with the _full_ output?

Comment: Agreed.  The issue I had ended up heading down a path that was unrelated to the listed error.  Unfortunately, I no longer had the full output.

Comment: Similar issue answered in this with a bit more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822779/mule-cookbook-anypoint-connector-build-failed/36828620#36828620