# Mule Cookbook Anypoint connector - build failed

Tags: maven-plugin, cookbook

pull this from this directory and perform a maven build
git clone https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-cookbook.git

The following is the error received towards the 2nd last step

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (default-enforce) on project cookbook-connector: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed with message:
[ERROR] Detected JDK Version: 1.8.0-77 is not in the allowed range [1.7,1.8).
```

I have tried to change POM.xml to [1.7, 1.9)
such POM is located under "mule-cookbook-parent"

There is no other POM pointing to the jdk range except this POM which is tagged as "archive"

Really have no idea where to go from here. Please help.

pC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mule-cookbook` has a sub-module, `cookbook-connector`, that uses DevKit 3.7.2. The problem here is that **DevKit 3.7.x is not compatible with JDK 1.8** but DevKit 3.8.x is.

So, either you use Java 1.7 to compile the `mule-cookbook`, or you modify the POM of the `cookbook-connector` project to use the latest DevKit:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.mule.tools.devkit</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-devkit-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.2</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much!!